# Rails 3 Order By Count on has_many :through

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, tagging

I have an application where I can list Items and add tags to each Item.
The models **Items** and **Tags** are associated like this:

```rb
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :tags, :through => :taggings
end

class Tagging < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item
  belongs_to :tag
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :items, :through => :taggings
end
```

So, this many-to-many relationship allows me to set **n** tags for each Item, and the same tag can be used several times.

I'd like to list all tags ordered by the number of items associated with this tag. More used tags, shows first. Less used, last.

How can I do that?

Regards.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Tag.joins(:taggings).select('tags.*, count(tag_id) as "tag_count"').group(:tag_id).order(' tag_count desc')
```

try it desc, asc and see the difference.

We need *select*, to have tag_count column, and we need tag_count column to apply *order* to it, rest all straight forward *join* and *grouping*.

Btw, why dont you try this out https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on

Comment: +1 Amol. Do you have any idea on how to accomplish this same query result but with another layer of has_many through:? My question [ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19537378/ordering-nested-has-many-through-by-count-of-associations ] would be analogous to goo's Items being members of Groups, then trying to list the Tags of an individual Group of Items in order of their frequency of use within the Group, rather than among all Items. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You'd hope there's a better way, but this worked for me (without the whitespace). Assume `name` is the name attribute of the Tag model.

```
foo = Tagging.select("name, count(item_id) as item_count")
      .joins("inner join tags on taggings.tag_id = tags.id")
      .group("name")
      .order("item_count DESC")

foo.each { |r| puts "number of items tagged #{r.name}: #{r.item_count}"}

-->"number of items tagged Bieber: 100"
-->"number of items tagged GofT: 99"
```