# Display Country with the most occurrences Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a country model and would like to display the  country with the most occurrences, country names are held in the column 'mame', however the country db is pre populated and the relationship is a country

```
has_many recipes
```

and recipe

```
 belongs_to country
```

So far I have

```
Country.group('name').order('count_name DESC').limit(1).count('name')
```

but this will not work will it as there are 1 of every country in the table? Do i need to do a count on the number of times the country_id is used? if so what would the syntax be for that? would it be

```
Recipe.group('country_id').order('count_country_id DESC').limit(1).count('country_id')
```

or using joins and select

```
Country.joins(:recipes).select('countries.*, count(country_id) as "country_count"').group(:country_id).order(' country_count desc')
```

Any pointers appreciated

Comment: See here for constructing the query yourself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957025/rails-3-order-by-count-on-has-many-through

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by using queries. However, RoR has built in support to achieve the same. It is called Counter Cache.

I can explain here but I think it's better if you follow this screencast.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column

This will give you very good idea how to use counter cache and get what you've tried to achieve.

Comment: you wont need then. please check the video and you will get idea. things will be much easier.